# Removing header from a text file

Tags: python

I have a text file that I am trying to import without the header. You can see my text file and the code that I wrote for importing it.

```
Elem, _LCC_, _DCC_
        2000001,+2.663e-02,+1.751e-01
        2000002,+2.667e-02,+1.758e-01
        2000003,+2.918e-02,+1.905e-01
        2000004,+2.988e-02,+1.928e-01
        2000005,+2.781e-02,+1.849e-01
        2000006,+2.656e-02,+1.735e-01
        2000007,+2.715e-02,+1.807e-01
        2000008,+2.838e-02,+1.875e-01
        2000009,+2.851e-02,+1.881e-01
        2000010,+2.740e-02,+1.825e-01
        2000011,+2.648e-02,+1.700e-01
        2000012,+2.876e-02,+1.890e-01
        2000013,+2.906e-02,+1.901e-01
        2000014,+2.659e-02,+1.743e-01
        2000015,+2.671e-02,+1.765e-01
```

Python code:

```
lc_empty_cp =[]
dc_empty_cp = []
with open(path_cp+'\DNV_E'+file_type,"r+") as f_de:
    for line_de in f_de:
        try:
            line_de = [float(x_de) for x_de in line_de.split()]
            lc_empty_cp.append(line_de[index_lc:index_lc+1])
            dc_empty_cp.append(line_de[index_dc:index_dc+1])
            lc_empty_cp.remove([])
            dc_empty_cp.remove([])
        except ValueError:
            continue
f_de.close()
```

This returns empty list for dc_empty_cp and lc_empty_cp. But the I would like to get is as follows:

```
[+2.663e-02 +1.751e-01
        +2.667e-02 +1.758e-01
        +2.918e-02 +1.905e-01
        +2.988e-02 +1.928e-01
        +2.781e-02 +1.849e-01
        +2.656e-02 +1.735e-01
        +2.715e-02 +1.807e-01
        +2.838e-02 +1.875e-01
        +2.851e-02 +1.881e-01
        +2.740e-02 +1.825e-01
        +2.648e-02 +1.700e-01
        +2.876e-02 +1.890e-01
        +2.906e-02 +1.901e-01
        +2.659e-02 +1.743e-01
        +2.671e-02 +1.765e-01]
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: The data is comma-separated, but you are splitting on whitespace. Skipping the first line is a common duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `csv` module:

```
import csv

lc_empty_cp = []
dc_empty_cp = []

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        lc_empty_cp.append(float(row[' _LCC_']))
        dc_empty_cp.append(float(row[' _DCC_']))
```

Output

```
>>> lc_empty_cp
[0.02663,
 0.02667,
 0.02918,
 0.02988,
 0.02781,
 0.02656,
 0.02715,
 0.02838,
 0.02851,
 0.0274,
 0.02648,
 0.02876,
 0.02906,
 0.02659,
 0.02671]

>>> dc_empty_cp
[0.1751,
 0.1758,
 0.1905,
 0.1928,
 0.1849,
 0.1735,
 0.1807,
 0.1875,
 0.1881,
 0.1825,
 0.17,
 0.189,
 0.1901,
 0.1743,
 0.1765]
```

You can combine them:

```
>>> list(zip(lc_empty_cp, dc_empty_cp))
[(0.02663, 0.1751),
 (0.02667, 0.1758),
 (0.02918, 0.1905),
 (0.02988, 0.1928),
 (0.02781, 0.1849),
 (0.02656, 0.1735),
 (0.02715, 0.1807),
 (0.02838, 0.1875),
 (0.02851, 0.1881),
 (0.0274, 0.1825),
 (0.02648, 0.17),
 (0.02876, 0.189),
 (0.02906, 0.1901),
 (0.02659, 0.1743),
 (0.02671, 0.1765)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using of [pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt')
output = df.to_csv(header=None,index=False)

print(output)
```

If `file.txt` has you content, then result is as follow:

```
2000001,0.02663,0.1751
2000002,0.02667,0.1758
2000003,0.02918,0.1905
2000004,0.02988,0.1928
2000005,0.02781,0.1849
2000006,0.02656,0.1735
2000007,0.02715,0.1807
2000008,0.02838,0.1875
2000009,0.02851,0.1881
2000010,0.0274,0.1825
2000011,0.02648,0.17
2000012,0.02876,0.189
2000013,0.02906,0.1901
2000014,0.02659,0.1743
2000015,0.02671,0.1765
```